# Depth first search won't return path, even if the path is there

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I am writing a function that traverses a 2d array using depth-first search. The problem I am running into is that my function is saving the path it took, but it won't return the values when found.

```
grid = grid_to_matrix(grid1)
def DFS(grid, node, visited=None,path = []):
    found = False
    if node.coord == end.coord:
        # print('found')
        found = True
    visited.add(node.coord)
    # print(f"Visiting {start.coord}")
    for adj in find_adjacent_nodes(grid, node):
        # print(f"Adjacent to {node.coord} is {adj.coord}")
        
        if adj.coord not in visited:
            # print(f"Visiting: {adj.coord}")
            path.append(adj.coord)
            # print(adj.coord)
            DFS(grid, adj, visited,path)
    if found:
        return path
```

Comment: shouldn't you return out of the function when you find the end coordinate after the first if check? you would need to mark the node as visited and pop out of the recursive call. also you may need to check the return of the recursive DFS call to know when to return out of the recursive function calls.

Comment: @Yash I initially tried to return the path from the initial if statement, but it still won't return anything. When I print path, it gives me the correct answer, but it won't return anything

Comment: it just depends on what you are returning. if you return `None` and then if you don't return out of the location of the recursive call as well then `None` will be returned up the call stack. 

you can try returning in the 2 places i mentioned in the above comment and that should solve the problem of nothing returning